# Two network connections split traffic

Tags: windows-7

I have two networks. One ADSL 2Mb and one HSPD modem 21Mb.
Adsl is connected to router. It seems that all traffic go there.

HSPA modem is faster, so it can transfer more data. But it has terrible ping time 500ms.
ADSL is fast, but slow.

I want split traffic, between networks. Some how useful way.

Answer (score 1):

You need a loadbalancer to split and configure the split behaviour of your cfonnections.

Maybe this will help: http://buyloadbalancers.com/lobare20.html

Comment: The link no longer works